# How does this loop run nlogn times? (for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2) )

Tags: data-structures

```
for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2)
```

How does this loop run nlogn times?
Code Fragment:

```
int unknown(int n) {

int i, j, k = 0;

for (i  = n/2; i <= n; i++)

    for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2)

        k = k + n/2;

return k;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner loop runs at most **log(n)** times not n*log(n).
The loop runs from 2 to n but here j increments as j=2*j. It's values will be 2,4,8,16,32,...n. so it runs log(n) times only.

Comment: I thought so too but the answer for the fragment is n^3*log(n), where the inner loop has n^2*log(n)

Comment: are you referring to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2013-question-31/) question? if yes, they asked value of k not time complexity

Answer (score 0):

for first loop

```
for (i  = n/2; i <= n; i++)
```

As we can see in above loop value of *i* is increasing by 1 every time.
Let us assume that the loop is executing some *k* times. At *k*th step *k* = *n*, and at (*k* + 1)th step we come out of the loop.

Total time require to execute this(first) loop is **O(n)**.

now, let consider inner loop

```
for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2)
```

If we observe carefully, the value of *j* is doubling every time. Initially *j* = 2, in next step *j* = 4, and in subsequent steps *j* = 8, 16 and so on.
Let us assume that the loop is executing some *k* times. At *k*th step 2^*k* = *n*, and at (*k* + 1)th step we come out of the loop. Taking logarithm on both sides, gives

```
log(2^k) = logn

klog2 = logn

k = logn   // we have assume base-2
```

Total time require to execute inner loop is **O(logn)**.

> Total time for given algorithm = (first_loop_time_complexity) *
> (inner_loop_time_complexity)

so, total time for given algorithm is

> **Total time = O(nlogn).**

Comment: The first loop is linear, not log(n)

Comment: @ColouredPanda :- thanks for your review. I have written it by mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: In the inner loop k is increasing by n/2 every time so it also has time O(n) which would give total time to be O((n^2)*logn) but the given answer is O((n^3)*logn) which i don't know how they are getting

Comment: @Ritvik :- Could you please elaborate more. As per my understanding time complexity of given algorithm is O(nlogn) and k is constant factor. if possible could you please give an example where you find time complexity of O(n^3*logn) of a given algorithm. it is helpful to understand.

Comment: @HarishShisode , the answer give for the question was  O(n^3*logn) which I don't know how they got hence the question and about the extra n (from the answer i think it should be, i.e. n^2*logn) if you look inside the inner loop, it is raising the value by n/2 and not a constant value making it order n time hence giving you n * n * logn = n^2*logn

Comment: It seems that you would like to know the value of k returned not the time complexity. In that case value of k return should be (n^2logn)

Comment: Thanks @HarishShisode I misread the answer, time complexity is theta( n^2 log n), i didn't check properly, I'm sorry